# Combine IronPython's and CLI stack trace

Tags: ironpython

I have an application written in IronPython which uses classes and methods from imported .NET assembly (compiled with debug support). When a method in assembly throws an exception, it gets caught in IronPython code as Exception (not System.Exception) and the traceback ends at last IronPython method.

What I would like to do is to go deeper and append the original CLI traceback after last IronPython method to see where the exception occured inside the assembly.

Is it possible to get original CLI exception from caught IronPython equvivalent or catch it without loosing IronPython's stack trace?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ExceptionOperations object from scriptEngine.GetService().   You can then call FormatException or GetStackFrames. You can also set the ExceptionDetail option to true to get more verbose stack traces from FormatException.